# Correct circuit element alternative to transistors

Tags: transistors, relay, stepper-motor

First please see my proteus file to understand what am I trying to do.
http://www.docdroid.net/ru27/yenitasarim.pdf.html

As you see, there is 5 button groups vertical and 5 button groups horizontal.
Each button group has 4 buttons. Assume that each vertical button groups ar signed as A,B,C,D,E and horizontals are 1,2,3,4,5

So, When I want to run the stepper on A1, I'm seting pushed all buttons on A and 1
I can run multiple steppers too, I can simply set pushed the button groups at horizontal and vertical, then concurdend steppers will start to run.

This system works good If I set the buttons manually. But I don't want to use buttons and I don't want to run it manually.

Then I have tried this kind of a design, [image: New Design]

As you can see, I have removed buttons and placed transistors. Also there is one transistor that trigs the others. I can send 3.3v to the base of Q5 and make all transitors work.

But, my problem starts here, When I set votage on Q5 base, this voltage flows on all transistors from base to emiter, but as you know, stepper motors drivers generates voltage in a sequence. Flowing voltage from base to emiter corrups the voltage that comes from stepper driver.

Better way to use a relay, it is isolated between vires, but it doesn't work fast.

What is the best solution? I need an element that works as fast as transitors and isolated like relay.

Thanks all.

Comment: I don't see any stepper driver in your schematic. We'd be able to give you better answers if you share a more complete schematic.

Comment: Another option: connect emitter of Q5 to collector of Q1-Q4, and connect the phase control inputs to the bases of Q1-Q4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you need, you can do something as simple as this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffmOcO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Signals `Vx` and `Hx` are the inputs from the Arduino indicating that the x'th vertical and horizontal motor should be enabled. Signals `phi0` -- `phi3` are the control signals coming from the stepper controller. Signals `dr0` -- `dr3` are the outputs to the 4 drive transistors for the motor.

You don't need a separate "switch" for each of the four phases. A single switch (AND1) can control enabling all 4 phases.

And, so far as I can see you don't need "isolation like a relay" (galvanic isolation). You just need signal isolation between the two sets of inputs.

Comment: The design with the PIC controller only shows 6 I/O line remaining.  A 5x5 control matrix would require 10 I/O lines.

Comment: @Nedd, My understanding is that the PIC is being used as a stepper controller and is producing the `phi` signals. The `Vx` and `Hx` signals are being produced by an Arduino board (as mentioned in OP's schematic snippet) which is being added to the system. So the number of free I/O's on the PIC is not important.

Comment: And in any case, OP could use a shift register to generate 25 I/O's from three. But we've discussed that in many prior questions so we don't need to go into it here.

Answer (score 0):

With your present arrangement you are using 40 switches to control 25 motors. If you were to enable each motor with an XY pair of lines you could reduce this to 10 switches (or 10 I/O lines) set up in a 5x5 matrix.  However if you want to use I/O lines from your present PIC controller it seems that you only have 6 spare lines.  You need a way to expand these to the required 10 lines (or 25 lines). A well controlled shift register can accomplish this.

By using two 74HC4094 chips (or CD4094) Shift Register chips you could control 10 lines (or up to 16 lines) with only 4-I/O lines.  But by using four of these chips you could individually control each of the 25 (or up to 32) motors with the same 4-I/O lines.  You could actually expand this further by cascading even more chips.

To load the shift register with the motor enable data: (if using 25 separate enable lines)
Start with CLOCK, DATA, STROBE, and OUT_ENABLE low.
Send 25 data bits and 25 clock pulses to the DATA and CLOCK lines,
Pulse the STROBE pin,
Set OUT_ENABLE high.
The 25 bits of data are sent to the 25 motor control lines, (Mx_EN).
(Note: See the 74HC4094 or CD4049 data sheet to be sure of the pulse directions.)

http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/308/MC74HC4094A-D-97351.pdf

http://www.jaycar.com/images_uploaded/CD4094BC.PDF

Because the chip uses two sets of internal registers you could have the motors running while you are sending new data for changing the motor arrangement.  The OUT_ENABLE line could be used to disable all motors at once. If you are careful with the motor timing you may be able to change the running motor arrangement on the fly by leaving the OUT_ENABLE high then pulsing the STROBE pin to immediately output the new motor data.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuuimx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In this format each additional shift register chip can control the enable input of 8 motors.

If you need some type of complete isolation you could place opto-couplers either on the I/O lines coming from the controller, or on each motor sub-group.